# How do I display or report the number of issues from more than one JIRA filters?

Tags: jira

We use JIRA to track issues. I have to produce a monthly report on the number of open issues in various groups of projects. I've created filters for each group. I would like to create a dashboard that shows:

1. The number of issues reported by each filter, preferably without showing the issue list as well.
2. Totals for various sets of filters.

What's the best way to do this? Can it be done without writing my own report or gadget?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. For that issue, I created a function to get the total number of issues for each Jira query like this below.

1. Create a new spreadsheet (in google sheets)
2. List your own Jira queries / filters from up to down without double quotation mark.

   Instead of double quotation mark, just use single quotation mark. “ => ‘
3. Download / Export this spreadsheet as a CSV file.
4. Now go back to your Jira => Advanced Search page then open inspect and console 
   https://yourprojectdomainname.atlassian.net/issues/?jql=
5. Copy & Paste the following code below into the console.
6. Once you call this function, a "Choose File" input will appear.
7. Click the "choose file" input and select the csv file that you've just downloaded.
8. Once you select it, Jira queries will be triggered automatically and the number of issues will be listed.

Once it's done, you will be able to copy and paste them in to the next column in your report spreadsheet.

```
$("#search-header-view").after('<input type="file" id="the-file-input" /><div id="theContainer"></div>');
console.log("Author: MertKGursoy");
function theReader(e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  if (!file) {
    return;
  }
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    var cont = e.target.result;
    theParsed(cont);
  };
  reader.readAsText(file);
}
function theParsed(cont) {
 const json = cont.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
  var theText = JSON.stringify(json);
  theText = theText.replace(/\[/g, "");
  theText = theText.replace(/\]/g, "");
  theText = theText.replace(/\\n/g, "");
  theText = theText.replace(/\\r/g, '", "');
  theText = theText.replace(/\\/g, '"');
  var str = theText;
  var str_array = str.match(/(".*?"|[^",\s]+)(?=\s*,|\s*$)/g);
  var theLength = str_array.length + 1;
  for(var i = 0; i < theLength ; i++) {
            delay(i);
  }
  function delay (i) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            str_array[i] = str_array[i].replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "");
            var jqlQuery = str_array[i];
            var withoutdoublequotes = jqlQuery.replace(/\"/g, '');
            var text = document.getElementById('advanced-search');
            text.value = withoutdoublequotes;
            var jqlValue = document.getElementById("jql").value;
            $(".aui-button-primary").trigger("click");
            if (withoutdoublequotes) {    
                setTimeout(() => {
                    var resultValue = $('.results-count-total').first().text();
                    if (resultValue) {
                        $("#theContainer").append(resultValue  + '<br>');
                    } else {
                        resultValue = "0";
                        $("#theContainer").append(resultValue  + '<br>');  
                    }
                 }, 3000);
            } else {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    resultValue = "-";
                    $("#theContainer").append(resultValue  + '<br>');                      
                }, 3000);         
            }
        },i * 6000);
 }
}
document.getElementById('the-file-input').addEventListener('change', theReader, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jira's remote API](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+Remote+API+Reference) to make the searches, [example](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+API+Example+-+Query+issues) using REST API:

```
curl -D- -u fred:fred -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://kelpie9:8081/rest/api/2/search?jql=assignee=fred
```

Write an html page, making the ajax calls to the API, and displaying what ever you need to the screen. Than use Text Gadget to add this page to the dashboard.

A more efficient way might be to run a cron job every 5 minutes or so, create this page, save it to Jira's web directory, than use ajax call to get the file content and to display it to the screen. If you choose this solution you can use [Jira's CLI](https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/display/JCLI/JIRA+Command+Line+Interface) to get the statistics.